# Is it possible to transcribe Indian music (especially vocal ornamentation) in western-style sheet music?

Tags: sheet-music, indian-classical

I recently learned that Indian music basically uses the same 12 notes that we see in western music and that at one of the main reasons why it sounds so foreign is the vocal ornamentation. For example I was told that one of them is called Zamzama and I wouldn't even know how to begin on transcribing that in western sheet music. To me it sounds like some extreme form of vibrato, sometimes stretching across multiple semitones while staying within certain pattern boundaries.

I tried to find Indian sheet music to understand how they would notate something like that, but I'm just completely lost when I look at it. For example:

[image]

This is so far from what I'm used to that I wouldn't even have guessed it to be some form of sheet music.

Now I'm curious if Indian music with all its ornamentation etc could even be represented in western-style sheet music.

Comment: Important philosophical point: even Western notation has never depicted “everything that happens.” Some amount of the end product is always added by unwritten, sometimes even unconscious, convention.

Comment: Honestly, if I tried transcribed my full singing (of the melody of a video game theme, say) into Western notation, I'd have trouble, too. Smooth portamentos spanning a 5th or more, tremolos involving notes more than a whole tone apart, special effects involving my voice purposefully breaking up (at a certain note), strong vocal attacks (of starts of notes)....

Comment: Maybe you can include the spectrogram along the regular sheet music or make up your own ornamentation symbols.